# bootstrap tabbable not switching

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. Although there are many questions asked on this issue but still i cannot figure out what is going wrong. When i click on second or third tab the content does not change.

```
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li ><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1"><p>Tab1 Content</p></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"><p>Tab2 Content</p></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3"><p>Tab3 Content</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: keep js file out of the body

Answer (score 0):

You're including the bootstrap.min.js file **before** jquery.js. It should be included **after** jquery.js.

Just change it to:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

include bootstrap.min.js and jquery.js before body.

something like this

```
<head>
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

body content goes here

</body>
```